Как идентифицировать роль ServerBooster в Discord, если на сервере изменили ее имя. C#
Роль ServerBooster создает сам Discord, когда серверу первый раз кто-то из пользователей дает буст. Прямо сейчас у меня есть код, который находит эту роль по ее первоначальному названию ServerBooster, но я узнала, что это название можно изменять. Как еще можно идентефицировать эту особую роль? По каким параметрам?
Вот так я пока нахожу эту роль:
var serverBoosterRole = Guild.Roles.FirstOrDefault(x => x.IsManaged && x.Name == "ServerBoosterRole");
Какие-то другие роли наверняка могут являться IsManaged == true, поэтому только на этом параметре не вывезти.

Сейчас поняла, что параметр IsManaged указывает на связь с какой-то интеграцией, и что таких может быть очень много самых разных. Так что только один этот параметр для поиска точно не катит

x.Tags.IsPremiumSubscriberRole

@EvgeniyZ Спасибо большое!!
